# Cassandra - DS Bulk Loader VS DS Bulk Migrator VS Cassandra Data Migrator

Tags: cassandra, datastax

How can you decide between these 3 tools for data migration?  The DataStax documentation says the bulk migrator is for small data while the data migrator is for large data but both of these use the bulk loader under the hood which datastax says can be used for large data and production.  After playing around with all 3 I can't really see why one would be better than the other besides for the cassandra data migrator not needing to generate intermediate CSV files.  They all seem to be able to record failures.

Documentation https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/migrate/migrate-and-validate-data.html

I have used all three tool and expected to be able to find different use cases for each.  There is not a lot of information besides what is on the datastax website.